# Servlet filter mapped on /* results in browser error "server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete"

Tags: servlets, redirect, browser, servlet-filters

I am developing a dynamic JSP/Servlet web application. In order to handle the session, I am using a filter which is mapped on `/*` in `web.xml`. When I'm opening a page in Firefox, it gives the following Firefox-specific error message:

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete

A similar error is shown in Chrome. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter is redirecting to an URL which is invoking the very same filter with the very same conditions again which in turn thus results in a new redirect, etcetera. Your filter is basically redirecting to itself in an infinite loop. The webbrowser is blocking the infinite loop after ~20 requests to save the enduser from badly designed webapplications.

You need to fix your filter accordingly that it is not performing a redirect when it has already been performed. Let's assume a basic real world example of a login filter which is mapped on `/*` which should be redirecting to the login page when the user is not logged in which is identified by `user` attribute in session. You obviously want that the filter should not redirect to the login page if the login page itself is currently been requested.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";

        boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null;
        boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL);

        if (loggedIn || loginRequest) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response); // Logged-in user found or already in login page, so just continue request.
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(loginURL); // No logged-in user found and not already in login page, so redirect to login page.
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

You see, if you want to allow/continue a request, just call `chain.doFilter()` instead of `response.sendRedirect()`. Use redirect only if you want to change a request to a different destination.